# colorbox not working with ajax framework

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I am using D7 ajax framework. I have created a link which loads a node in a div by click. But colorbox doesn't work on these nodes. Images has a class colorbox but not the rest like colorbox-init etc.

Comment: Could you please show the code? Have you included colorbox JS in those pages?

Comment: website is http://kafe.aweb.kz, do i have to include it manually? Isn't it automatically?

Comment: which page/block/content uses the colorbox?

Comment: You have to press on the menu item called "ФОТООТЧЕТЫ". It's div with ID = photos. Press on any thumbnail then you will see node images.

Comment: I think what he is asking here, is when ajax loads his node (which has a colorbox image) into a div. then it doesnt work. This is because the scripts that init a colorbox link are not called when the node is loaded via ajax into the div, because only the node content is loaded, not the scripts that init colorbox links. the solution would be to call the colobox scripts that init the links so that they can open into a colorbox. Dont ask me how to do that though, I'm trying to figure it out myself. If I find out I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

According to the colorbox module documentation,

> **Load content in a Colorbox**
>
> Check the "Enable Colorbox load" option in Colorbox settings.
> This enables custom links that can open content in a Colorbox. Add the class "colorbox-load" to the link and build the url like this "[path]?width=500&height=500&iframe=true" or "[path]?width=500&height=500" if you don't want an iframe.
>
> Other modules may activate this for easy Colorbox integration.

First, you have to check Colorbox configuration

Then, you need to edit your view to add custom class to your link.
Ajax link may not be required in your case, because Colorbox module will open your content with it's own manner...

But I can't test this point, so check with and without and edit this answer :).

**Links**

[Documentation page](https://drupal.org/node/1971564)